why there are int56_t in clang c header file, and how to use them
I noticed that
https://android.googlesource.com/platform/prebuilts/clang/host/linux-x86/+/refs/heads/nougat-mr1-security-release/clang-2690385/lib64/clang/3.8/include/stdint.h#128
#ifdef __INT56_TYPE__
typedef __INT56_TYPE__ int56_t;
typedef __UINT56_TYPE__ uint56_t;
typedef int56_t int_least56_t;
typedef uint56_t uint_least56_t;
typedef int56_t int_fast56_t;
typedef uint56_t uint_fast56_t;

I searched google but find nothing. And it's even my first time to notice these types.

Sounds like a good question to ask at https://retrocomputing.stackexchange.com/ - maybe someone knows the reason behind it.

It looks like that linked stdint.h is missing some #undefs and could multiply define some macros such as __int_least32_t.

The comment in that header file before those types (link to GitHub commit adding these) explains:

To accomodate targets that are missing types that are exactly 8, 16, 32, or
64 bits wide, this implementation takes an approach of cascading
redefintions, redefining __int_leastN_t to successively smaller exact-width
types. It is therefore important that the types are defined in order of
descending widths.

Whether such machines exist (anymore?) in the wild is a good question, but LLVM/clang would support them.
In short, to answer "how to use them":
You don't, unless you have an esoteric machine that defines __INT56_TYPE__.

The Motorola 56000 DSP perhaps ? (e.g. in an Atari Falcon).

@Michael There are a few 28 and 56-bit DSPs
